# External monitor is washed out with Intel HD Graphics

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, external-display, intel-graphics, dell-xps

I recently bought a Dell XPS 15 with an Intel HD Graphics 530 installed.

Here is what my monitor should look like:
[image: displaying correctly]

And this is what my monitor looks like when I say it is:
[image: washed out]

So this problem seems to be occurring whenever I right click on my desktop, and select *Graphics Options > Output To* and then select my secondary display. However, the problem first occurred if I had an HDMI cable plugged in before I had unlocked the laptop.

Since then I attempted to uninstall the Intel HD Graphics driver, which caused the laptop to restart. Once restarted, the video card automatically reinstalled the driver and the problem appeared to go away. However, if I restarted the laptop again the problem returned. **So the problem seems to disappear if the laptop is started without the driver installed, but if it is already installed on start up, then the problem occurs.**

A peculiar thing I noticed as well is if I select 'Second screen only' from the Windows 10 project menu, the monitor will sometimes not appear washed out, however if I select it from the Intel HD Graphics menu, then it will appear washed out as long as the laptop booted up with the drivers already installed.

A couple other symptoms I noticed since trying to update the graphics driver are **black right-angle triangles** seem to appear on pop-up menus, **but only on the secondary display**. Also, **the desktop background will go black and I will only be able to select colors from the personalize menu, not an image.**

**Does anyone have any idea what is going on and how I could fix this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it turned out to be a case of Intel's driver not working properly. To fix it I downloaded the 11/9/2016 Intel Graphics Driver version (Version: 15.45.10.4542) [from here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26404/Intel-Graphics-Driver-15-45-?product=80939).

However to get the installer to run I had to run it in Troubleshoot Compatability mode and run the installer using Windows 8 drivers as Intel hadn't upgraded to Windows 10 correctly.

Answer (score 7):

This is what worked in my case. My monitor was being incorrectly detected as a HDTV with limited range and adding a custom resolution with "CVT-RB" timing fixed it.

You can add a custom resolution either in *Intel HD Control panel > Display > Advanced > Add custom resolution* or, in case you have newer drivers, you need to run `CustomModeApp.exe` manually (via `Win+R`), which is the same utility.

There you can add your custom resolution. When it asks if you'd like to overwrite the existing one, click yes. This should force the full RGB range and fix the washed out colors.

[image]

This is what you'd use for a standard FullHD monitor. Again, be sure to select `CVT-RB`.

Comment: This is a terrific, permanent fix, @blade. It associates the correct FullHD settings to a device that the Intel driver erroneously "detects" as a TV.  By saving this custom setting and using it as default, the driver stops trying to revert to the wrong settings when the computer is restarted.  Brilliant!  I'd give this 5 votes if I could.

Comment: God, I was struggling with this issue 2 year after I bought Asus laptop..
Though graphics driver properly detects external monitor name (thus, I assume, correctly understands that it's a _monitor_), it still displays not full black.
The fix completely solved the problem, thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible in Intel Graphics Command Center. 

Answer (score 3):

How To Geek may have [the answer](http://www.howtogeek.com/285277/how-to-avoid-washed-out-colors-when-using-hdmi-on-your-pc/)! Essentially HDMI sometimes defaults to RGB Limited. You need to go into your graphics card control panel and change it to RGB Full. On Intel cards it's at the bottom of the General tab according to HTG's instructions.

Comment: Having fixed the problem, I've just tried setting it to RGB limited, and the result wasn't nearly as extreme as when the problem was occuring, so I think it was just due to a crumby driver to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me. I think it might be the same root solution as @blade mentioned but with the new control panel. Intel HD Graphics Control Panel > Display > Quantization Range > Select Full Range.

Mine was previously set to 'Default Range' which gave the same result as Low Range. After selecting Full Range and then clicking Default Range, the problem did not reoccur, so I think the problem is that the default range is being incorrectly detected initially.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Such washed out image is caused by monitor expecing "Full range RGB" signal but the GPU is sending "Limited range RGB".

The limited range RGB is used for historical reasons on TVs whereas full range is historically used with computer monitors.

Poor fix is to change the monitor to limited range RGB mode. This will result in correct white and black limits but will cause more banding in colors.

A good fix is to locate the correct setting in display driver (GPU) settings. Some drivers have explicit setting for Full Range RGB vs Limited Range RGB, some drivers require selecting slightly different video mode. The technical reason for video mode affecting the RGB range is that *historically* TVs and monitors have used slightly different signal timing even for the same resolution (e.g. 1080p) and some manufacturers have decided to use the selected signal timing as the flag to automatically switch between limited range and full range RGB.

The technical difference is that full range RGB uses full 8 bit range from integer value 0 to 255 where 0 is black and 255 is white. Limited range RGB transmits the image with 8 bit integers but all values 0-35 result in black and all values 235-255 result in white. As a result, the image is actually using only integer values 35-235 meaning you get better compability with old displays but lose about 22% of all possible colors due less effective bits available for the signal.

If GPU and display are both compatible, you *always* want full range RGB support.